# What is a Service Contract in WCF?

Tags: wcf, service, contract, servicecontract

What exactly is a service contract in WCF? I can't seem to be able to find a clear definition of what is it. If you have have a link that defines what it is that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Service Contract" is an interface which has been marked with the [`ServiceContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx).  This is the API that gets "pushed" across the wire in WCF, and the main way to define the contract that is used for communication between the client and service.

For details, see [Designing Service Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/designing-service-contracts) on MSDN.